# Pass void to void with PInvoke

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I had a problem passing a managed void to a c++ void. Do you kow how to properly do it?
Here's my c++ code which gets a void(__cdecl* disph)() as parameter

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void Display(void(__cdecl* disph)());
```

And my question is how can I pass a simple void() (for example public static void Display())
to that c++ void.

Comment: `() => functionname()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about passing function pointers, right? `void`s are not passed, as there is nothing to be passed because it is, errr, void.

If I understood correctly, you need to pass a pointer to a function which takes no parameters and returns nothing, right? I am not at a Windows machine at the moment so this is untested, but something like this should work:

```
public delegate void VoidFnDelegate();
public value struct MyDLL
{
    [DllImport("MyDll.dll")]
    static public void Display(VoidFnDelegate fn);
}
...

void SomeFn() { ... }

MyDll.Display(new VoidFnDelegate(SomeFn));
```

Comment: I started the program but right before it started it throw an exception saying:
A call to PInvoke function 'Game!Game.Graphics::Display' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.